# Tkinter 'space' binding and entry clearing

Tags: python, tkinter

Okay, so I am making a typing speed test in Tkinter. I want the entry to clear when pressing space. Which it does, however, because space is bound as the key to clear the entry it's as if though Tkinter clears the entry and then adds space to the entry thereafter. Meaning, that after entering the first word, from there on out there is always a space at the beginning of the entry before you start typing the next word.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (MRE).

Comment: Call `return "break"` after clearing the entry.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your desired behaviour by returning `"break"`. This will make sure that the event doesn't propagate to other handlers.

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def handle(event):
    entry.delete("0", "end")
    return "break"

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

entry.bind("<space>", handle)

root.mainloop()
```

Also as @TheLizzard pointed out you could also try: `entry.bind("<KeyRelease-space>", handle)`

```
import tkinter as tk

def handle(event):
    entry.delete("0", "end")

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

entry.bind("<KeyRelease-space>", handle)

root.mainloop()
```

Also, something to note is that the second solution will add a space then delete, whereas the first one simply deletes the text without any added space.

Comment: Also you might want to add it to your answer but if you really don't want to `return `"break"` for some reason, you can bind to `"<KeyRelease-space>"` instead.

Comment: @TheLizzard sure, I have updated my answer based on your comment.